# How do I check to see if an object or its children/sub-objects has a property/key in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, object, recursion, properties

What I am looking for is basically a hasOwnProperty() or 'in' function which is recursive and looks down the chain to see if a key or property exists in an object.

For example I have the object:

```
var user = {
  username: "Derpette",
  profile: {
    role: 'admin',
    sex: 'female',
    emails:['derpette42@derpmail.com']
    }
}
```

I want to know if there is a key/property 'role' anywhere in the object or its sub-objects.
So I want to be able to call something like `user.hasProperty('role')` and it would return `true`.

Right now I am using if statements with a chain of assertions to check but it doesn't seem clean, especially for deep nested properties.

For example I would do:

```
if(user && user.profile && user.profile.role){
    //Manipulate/Use user.profile.role here
}
```

Another example of a use-case for this is if I am filtering mongoDB update modifiers coming from a client. I want to make sure they aren't updating their own role so I need to check that the property 'role' isn't somewhere in their mongoDB modifier json object. But it could be in a few places in a modifier so doing the if property chaining doesn't work well for this case.

Do I need to write my own recursive hasOwnProperty? I am thinking that something like this should already exist somewhere in a project like jquery or underscores.js or sugar.js but I can't seem to find it.

Comment: I'm pretty sure there isn't one. But you could easily make a function that does so

Comment: For example: http://jsfiddle.net/N82aZ/2/

Answer (score 4):

You could do this recursively:

```
function recHasProp(obj, prop) {
    for (var p in obj) {
        if (obj.hasOwnProperty(p)) {
            if (p === prop) {
                return obj;
            } else if (obj[p] instanceof Object && recHasProp(obj[p], prop)) {
                return obj[p];
            }
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

Usage:

```
var obj = recHasProp(user, 'role');
if (obj) {
    // obj.role exists, and obj is user or a child of user
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I really made use of this :) thumbsup

Answer (score 3):

My take on this, it's not pretty, but it's very performant in the few lines that it is.

```
function hasProp(obj, propPath, i) {
      if (typeof(i) === 'undefined' && !(i=0)) {
        propPath = propPath.split('.');
      }
      if (typeof(obj[propPath[i]]) !== 'undefined') {
        return (++i && i !== propPath.length) ? hasProp(obj[propPath[i - 1]], propPath, i) : true;
      }
      return false;
};
```

Usage Example (in your case):

```
hasProp(user, 'profile.role');
```

Plunker:
http://plnkr.co/edit/CIePivi3XcTEugFzEUyt?p=preview